# filter results based on average on other table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have these models, Venue, Review, User.
a User can score several venues. my reviews table looks like this:

```
Schema::create('reviews', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->integer('venue_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('venue_id')->references('id')->on('venues')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->tinyInteger('score');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

scores are calculated on the fly for every venue.
now How can filter those venues who have score , say, more than 3.

Comment: Please post your code for models & schema

Comment: @ ARIF MAHMUD RANA which part you mean?

Comment: Code for **`Venue, Review, User`** Model & Schema

Comment: @ARIF MAHMUD RANA [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32432794/filter-results-based-on-model-method)